# Batch - Looping in 'FileNames_Constant.Ext' , and Print 'FileNames' as an Output

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I've got some `*.Xml` files in a directory and its sub-directories.  I need to loop through the `XML` files which have a specific constant at the end of their file name, and then echo/print their names *without the constant part nor the extension (`.Xml`)*.

For example: these are the file names I have:

```
FileAAA_Constant.Xml
FileBBB.Xml
FileCCC.Xml
FileDDD_Constant.Xml
```

And this is the output I need:

```
FileAAA
FileDDD
```

I've tried this command:

```batch
For /R %%X in (*_Constant.Xml) do echo %%~nX
```

Which outputs this:

```
FileAAA_Constant
FileDDD_Constant
```

As you can see, it has removed the extension only, while I need to remove "`_Constant.Xml`" as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works if the file names contains only one underscore, as indicated in your example:

```
for /F "delims=_" %%X in ('dir /S /B *_Constant.Xml') do echo %%X
```

If the desired file names may contain more than one underscore, use Pokechu22's answer.

Comment: Actually all of the file names, have one under_score only, so your command is perfect... Appreciate Your Help :)

Answer (score 2):

Fairly easy if the exact length of the phrase is known; you just need to use the `%var:~0,-3%` syntax.  Since "`_Constant`" is 9 chars long, you would want `%var:~0,-9%`, which takes text from the start (`0`) to 9 chars from the end (`-9`).  Aditionally, delayed variable expansion also must be enabled with `setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` for this to be run inside of your `For` loop.

Here's a full example:

```batch
@Echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /R %%X in (*_Constant.Xml) do (
  set FileNameTemp=%%~nX
  echo !FileNameTemp:~0,-9!
)
```

Note that if you have a file named just `_Constant.xml`, this will produce "`ECHO is off.`" rather than "" (no output).  This can be solved by changing `echo !FileNameTemp:~0,-9!` to `echo. !FileNameTemp:~0,-9!`, but that puts a space before each output.

---

Here's the loop alone:

```batch
for /R %%X in (*_Constant.Xml) do (
  set FileNameTemp=%%~nX
  echo !FileNameTemp:~0,-9!
)
```

Comment: Thanks **Pokechu22** For Your Reply, I didn't expect to have any answer that fast! However, I don't think I can use your command, because what I'm asking about is just a very small part of a big batch file, that's why I've provided that Loop command , wishing that someone could modify it a bit easier, so I can add it to my batch without causing problems to the other commands. by the way, the constant part that I meant, is (by coincidence) 9 letters "**_adjusted**" but I don't know if this might help.. Anyway, Thank you so much for trying to help.. Have a good time bro :)

Comment: @KarimAlHousiny The only important part here is the for-loop, which I think you can edit into your file.  I've edited my answer to include the loop by itself as well; can this be used?

Comment: Thanks So Much Bro.. I've tested your new command on my batch, and it's working great as expected.. Thanks again for your help and support :)